# Allow large file upload from browser while navigating to other page

Tags: django, file-upload, google-app-engine-python

I'm building a website with Django 1.11 with a fairly simple javascript/html/css part (no framework like Vuejs). I have page reload on each navigation which is fine for my use case.

For convenience, I serve my website from App Engine Standard and it's going well so far. Now, I need my user to be able to upload files (up to 300MB size). Due to App Engine's [limitation on request size](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Requests) (32MB), I'm using [signed urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) so I can send these files directly from my client's Javascript to Cloud Storage.

Due to the size of the files, the upload may take some time, but I can't seem to navigate to another page since it may cancel the upload. I understand that for a case like this a client app like single-page app in Vuejs for example would be appropriate but is there a way to achieve this with my current setup without rewriting my whole website (with possibly Vuejs and Django REST API)?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you wait until the file gets uploaded?

Comment: I could wait until upload has completed you're right, that would be fine for stable/fast network connections. But if my user has bad connection, I guess the upload could take a lot of time and block the user from doing something else.

Comment: Your user can do other things in a new tab. I don't think it's worth it to worry about this thing unless majority of your users have slow network. Anyway, HTML 5 provides *resume-able* file uploads. This library seems to make the task easier - http://www.resumablejs.com/